# How to parse the output of Pandas' stack() function

Tags: python, pandas

`stack()` is an excellent Pandas function. It return `Stacked dataframe or series`. How to parse this output and print it well-formatted (like using to_markdown() function)?

```
>>>> df_single_level_cols
     weight height
cat       0      1
dog       2      3

>>>> df_single_level_cols.stack()
cat  weight    0
     height    1
dog  weight    2
     height    3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean that with to_markdown the two columns are displayed as tupels, right? Then try to use:

```
print(df_single_level_cols.stack().reset_index().to_markdown())
```

Maybe you have to adjust the ibdex and the column names.